# SetInterval play sound if class exist

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I made this snippet where this should search if inside a div there is an element with class "card-new-order"

The div with the id "comenzi" refreshes every 5 seconds and updates the cards inside and their classes.

If a card with a class is found play a sound until the script can't find that element.

Here is my code, but somehow can't make it to work.

```
var audio = document.getElementById("ring");
setInterval(function(){ 
    $('#comenzi').load(document.URL +  ' #comenzi'); 
    $('.contents > .card').each(function(i) {
        if($(this).hasClass('card-new-order')){
            audio.play();
        }else{
            audio.pause();
        }
    });

}, 5000);
```

Comment: can you be more precisely with what somehow doesn't works? do you have an error in your browser console?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to play/pause your audio element before the `load()` method has completed.

Consider revising your code, so that audio playback or pause occurs once the contents of the `load()` operation are available. You can do this by making use of [the `success` callback](https://api.jquery.com/load/) on the `load()` method:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("ring");
function refresh(){ 

    // Pass a success callback function to load() which is run after
    // the load has succeeded. Also, remove the whitespace before #comenzi
    $('#comenzi').load(document.URL +  '#comenzi', function() {

    // The loaded content from document.URL#comenzi have loaded and
    // can now be accessed
    $('.contents > .card').each(function(i) {

        if($(this).hasClass('card-new-order')){
            audio.play();
        } else {
            audio.pause();
        }
    });

    // Start the next cycle after the contents have loaded
    setTimeout(refresh, 5000)
    });     
}

// Start the refresh cycle
refresh();
```

Another suggestion shown above is to use `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval` to ensure that the next refresh happens after content has loaded from `load()`. The `setInterval` based approach runs the risk of calls to refresh() executing at once (which would happen if the server returning the content to `#comenzi` took longer than 5 seconds to respond, etc)

Hope this helps!